# regex to remove nested parenthesis brackets

Tags: r, regex, parsing, regex-negation, chemistry

How does one use regex expressions in R to replace the nested parenthesis in this example:

```
chf <- "(Mn,Ca,Zn)5(AsO4)2((AsO3)OH)24(H2O)(OH(AsO3))(OH(AsO3)OH)"
```

The desired output is

```
"(Mn,Ca,Zn)5(AsO4)2(AsO3OH)24(H2O)(OHAsO3)(OHAsO3OH)"
```

I'm trying this but I'm not able to exclude what's inside the nested brackets.

```
> str_replace_all(chf,"\\((\\w+)\\)","(gone)")

[1] "(Mn,Ca,Zn)5(gone)2((gone)OH)24(gone)(OH(gone))(OH(gone)OH)"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
library(gsubfn)
chf <- "(Mn,Ca,Zn)5(AsO4)2((AsO3)OH)24(H2O)(OH(AsO3))(OH(AsO3)OH)"
gsubfn("\\((?:[^()]++|(?R))*\\)", ~ gsub("(^\\(|\\)$)|[()]", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE), chf, perl=TRUE, backref=0)
# => [1] "(Mn,Ca,Zn)5(AsO4)2(AsO3OH)24(H2O)(OHAsO3)(OHAsO3OH)"
```

The [`\((?:[^()]++|(?R))*\)` regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses) is a known PCRE pattern to match nested parentheses. Once the match is found `gsubfn` takes the string and removes all non-initial and non-final parentheses using `gsub("(^\\(|\\)$)|[()]", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)`. Here, `(^\\(|\\)$)` matches and captures the first `(`  and last `)` into Group 1 and then any `(` and `)` are matched with `[()]`. The replacement is the contents of Group 1.

A base R equivalent solution:

```
chf <- "(Mn,Ca,Zn)5(AsO4)2((AsO3)OH)24(H2O)(OH(AsO3))(OH(AsO3)OH)"
gre <- gregexpr("\\((?:[^()]++|(?R))*\\)", chf, perl=TRUE)
matches <- regmatches(chf, gre)
regmatches(chf, gre) <- lapply(matches, gsub, pattern="(^\\(|\\)$)|[()]", replacement="\\1")
> chf
# => "(Mn,Ca,Zn)5(AsO4)2(AsO3OH)24(H2O)(OHAsO3)(OHAsO3OH)"
```

Comment: @val I added a base R solution, too.